# For loop not iterating

Tags: python, scrapy

I am completely stumped on this bug. I'm trying to pull all of the menu items from this page https://www.alloresto.fr/restaurant-livraison-a-domicile/restaurant/pizza-mia/angers-centre-ville/particuliers/carte. When it reaches the innermost for loop, it goes through one iteration and then moves on. This is very unexpected and I don't know what's causing it. The following is the function that is dedicated to parsing this page.

```
def get_menu(self, response):
    image_url = response.urljoin(response.xpath('//span/img/@src').extract_first())
    for menu_section in response.xpath("//div[@id = 'contenu_choixplats']/div"):
        menu_section_name = menu_section.xpath('dl/dt/text()').extract_first()
        for menu_item in menu_section.xpath('ul/li'):
            item = Restaurant()
            item['restaurant_url'] = response.url
            item['restaurant_name'] = response.request.meta['restaurant_name']
            item['street_name'] = response.request.meta['street_name']
            item['street_number'] = response.request.meta['street_number']
            item['city'] = response.request.meta['city']
            item['zip_code'] = response.request.meta['zip_code']
            item['food_type'] = response.request.meta['food_type']
            item['image_urls'] = [image_url]
            item['menu_category'] = menu_section_name
            item['menu_item_title'] = menu_item.xpath('div/h3/text()').extract()
            item['menu_item_details'] = menu_item.xpath('div/p/text()').extract_first()
            item['menu_item_price'] = menu_item.xpath('div').css('div.product-price-with-offer').xpath('p/text()').extract_first()
            yield item
```

Do you see anything that I am missing? Thank you for your time.

--UPDATE---

This is the complete code. I am supplying it in case the problem lies outside of the get_menu function. Note that the get_menu function only found after digging two pages deep from the index of the website.
spiders/alloresto_spider.py
    import scrapy
    import re
    from french_scraping.items import Restaurant

```
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "alloresto"
    allowed_domains = ['alloresto.fr']
    start_urls = ["https://www.alloresto.fr/livraison/villes/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li/a/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(sel.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.restaurants_for_this_city)

    def restaurants_for_this_city(self, response):
        for restaurant in response.xpath('//article/div'):
            restaurant_url = response.urljoin(restaurant.xpath('a/@href').extract_first())
            restaurant_name = restaurant.xpath('div/section[@class="restaurantDetails"]/h3/a/text()').extract_first()
            full_address = restaurant.xpath('div/section[@class="restaurantDetails"]/address/text()').extract_first()
            extracts = re.search(r'^([\d-]*?)\W(.*?),\W(.*?)\W(\d\d\d\d\d)', full_address)
            try:
                street_number = extracts.group(1)
            except:
                continue
            street_name = extracts.group(2)
            city = extracts.group(3)
            zip_code = extracts.group(4)
            food_type = restaurant.xpath('div/section/p').css('.restaurantCuisines').xpath('text()').extract()
            meta_data = {
                'restaurant_url': restaurant_url,
                'restaurant_name': restaurant_name,
                'street_number': street_number,
                'street_name': street_name,
                'city': city,
                'zip_code': zip_code,
                'food_type': food_type}
            yield scrapy.Request(restaurant_url, meta=meta_data, callback=self.get_menu)
        # get info on next page
        next_page = response.css('.next').xpath('a/@href').extract()
        if len(next_page) > 0:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page[0])
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.restaurants_for_this_city)

    def get_menu(self, response):
        image_url = response.urljoin(response.xpath('//span/img/@src').extract_first())
        for menu_section in response.xpath("//div[@id = 'contenu_choixplats']/div"):
            menu_section_name = menu_section.xpath('dl/dt/text()').extract_first()
            for menu_item in menu_section.xpath('ul/li'):
                item = Restaurant()
                item['restaurant_url'] = response.url
                item['restaurant_name'] = response.request.meta['restaurant_name']
                item['street_name'] = response.request.meta['street_name']
                item['street_number'] = response.request.meta['street_number']
                item['city'] = response.request.meta['city']
                item['zip_code'] = response.request.meta['zip_code']
                item['food_type'] = response.request.meta['food_type']
                item['image_urls'] = [image_url]
                item['menu_category'] = menu_section_name
                item['menu_item_title'] = menu_item.xpath('div/h3/text()').extract()
                item['menu_item_details'] = menu_item.xpath('div/p/text()').extract_first()
                item['menu_item_price'] = menu_item.xpath('div').css('div.product-price-with-offer').xpath('p/text()').extract_first()
                yield item
```

items.py

```
import scrapy

class Restaurant(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    restaurant_url = scrapy.Field()
    street_number = scrapy.Field()
    restaurant_name = scrapy.Field()
    street_name = scrapy.Field()
    city = scrapy.Field()
    zip_code = scrapy.Field()
    food_type = scrapy.Field()
    menu_category = scrapy.Field()
    menu_item_title = scrapy.Field()
    menu_item_details = scrapy.Field()
    menu_item_price = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'french_scraping'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['french_scraping.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'french_scraping.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '/Users/drew/Desktop/frenchscraping/french_scraping'
```

pipelines.py

```
class FrenchScrapingPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

Comment: it looks like it returns a generator: [What does the yield keyword do in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

Comment: So we've got the function, but how is it called?  Please provide a [mcve].  I suspect there's an issue in the call.

Comment: I've made an edit. Please see the complete code above.

Comment: Have you checked that subsequent loops contain an 'ul/li' element? If you're using ipython, insert a breakpoint and verify yourself what menu_section.x_path contains?

Comment: That's not the complete program, that's just a class definition.

Comment: I'm aware. The rest is very unlikely to be relevant but I can provide it if you would like.

Comment: I added all of the information that could possibly be relevant to this question. The rest of the files are all at their generated defaults.

Comment: @drewssp code that you have shared is working for me, i suspect that you, you might not be returning item from pipline after processing it, can you check that

Comment: @MrPandav I've added pipelines.py. Does it look right to you?

Comment: The pipline you are pointing to in settings file and defined in pipline is different

Comment: Try removing pipline line from settings file

Comment: My bad that is inbuilt image pipline and should not make anh different

Comment: I tried running the script again this morning and everything worked. I was tinkering with the script all day yesterday and the final script is not different from when it was when I posted this question. I would like to share with you where the issue was but I still do not know myself. Nonetheless I would like to thank you all for your time and effort at least, since I won't be able to choose a best answer that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

get_menu(self,response) is a generator, as it makes use of the yield statement.

When a generator function is called, it returns a generator object, without beginning execution of the function. For your code to run, you need to use get_menu(self,response) either within a ‘for’ loop or by passing it to any function or construct that iterates.